# Minimize function with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to do one task, but I just can't figure it out.

This is my function:

```
1/(x**1/n) + 1/(y**1/n) + 1/(z**1/n) - 1
```

I want that sum to be as close to 1 as possible.

And these are my input variables (x,y,z):

```
test = np.array([1.42, 5.29, 7.75])
```

So **n** is the only decision variable.

To summarize:

I have a situation like this right now:

```
1/(1.42**1/1) + 1/(5.29**1/1) + 1/(7.75**1/1) = 1.02229
```

And I want to get the following:

```
1/(1.42^(1/0.972782944446024)) + 1/(5.29^(1/0.972782944446024)) + 1/(7.75^(1/0.972782944446024)) = 0.999625
```

So far I have roughly nothing, and any help is welcome.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objectiv(xyz):
    x = xyz[0]
    y = xyz[1]
    z = xyz[2]
    n = 1
    return 1/(x**(1/n)) + 1/(y**(1/n)) + 1/(z**(1/n))

test = np.array([1.42, 5.29, 7.75])

print(objectiv(test))

OUTPUT: 1.0222935270013889
```

How to properly define a constraint?

```
def conconstraint(xyz):
x = xyz[0]
y = xyz[1]
z = xyz[2]
n = 1
return 1/(x**(1/n)) + 1/(y**(1/n)) + 1/(z**(1/n)) - 1
```

And it is not at all clear to me how and what to do with **n**?

EDIT

I managed to do the following:

```
def objective(n,*args):
    x = odds[0]
    y = odds[1]
    z = odds[2]
    return abs((1/(x**(1/n)) + 1/(y**(1/n)) + 1/(z**(1/n))) - 1)

odds = [1.42,5.29,7.75]

solve = minimize(objective,1.0,args=(odds))
```

And my output:

```
fun: -0.9999999931706812
x: array([0.01864994])
```

And really when put in the formula:

```
(1/(1.42^(1/0.01864994)) + 1/(5.29^(1/0.01864994)) + 1/(7.75^(1/0.01864994))) -1 = -0.999999993171
```

Unfortunately I need a positive 1 and I have no idea what to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find `n` that gets our result for a *fixed* x, y, and z as close as possible to `1`. `minimize` tries to get the lowest possible value for something, without negative bound; `-3` is better than `-2`, and so on.

So what we actually want is called [*least-squares*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) optimization. Similar idea, though. This documentation is a bit hard to understand, so I'll try to clarify:

All these optimization functions have a common design where you pass in a callable that takes at least one parameter, *the one you want to optimize for* (in your case, `n`). Then you can have it take more parameters, whose values will be *fixed* according to what you pass in.

In your case, you want to be able to solve the optimization problem for different values of x, y and z. So you make your callback accept n, x, y, and z, and pass the x, y, and z values to use when you call `scipy.optimize.least_squares`. You pass these using the `args` keyword argument (notice that it is not *args). We can also supply an initial guess of `1` for the `n` value, which the algorithm will refine.

The rest is customization that is not relevant for our purposes.

So, first let us make the callback:

```
def objective(n, x, y, z):
    return 1/(x**(1/n)) + 1/(y**(1/n)) + 1/(z**(1/n))
```

Now our call looks like:

```
best_n = least_squares(objective, 1.0, args=np.array([1.42, 5.29, 7.75]))
```

(You can call `minimize` the same way, and it will instead look for an `n` value to make the `objective` function return as low a value as possible. If I am thinking clearly: the guess for `n` should trend towards zero, making the denominators increase without bound, making the sum of the reciprocals go towards zero; negative values are not possible. However, it will stop when it gets close to zero, according to the default values for `ftol`, `xtol` and `gtol`. To understand this part properly is beyond the scope of this answer; please try on math.stackexchange.com.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, unfortunately I haven't been able to solve the problem yet. I will change the original post to see how far I have come.

Comment: I finally found a solution, I will post it in edit. Thanks for your help.